# Client-side registry for gRPC services obtained from Consul with persistent connection

Tags: go, grpc, consul, service-discovery

I have a Go service which is pluggable and based on the plugin serve different purposes. At the start it's register the address and port into the Consul's service discovery and it's tags like `plugin1`, `plugin2`, `plugin3`, etc.

On the client-side I want to connect to the services based on the plugin what it implements. I can get them from consul, call the `grpc.Dial` and pass it to the proto's client implementation. When I call the right endpoint I just close the connection and go on.

The problem with this, the `grpc.Dial` can be a reusable connection, so not necessary to call it anytime when I want to connect to a service, but it's too dynamic to have a persistent connection to the services, because services could be removed or new services can appear.

What is the best way to have persistent connection to the services based on this requirements/problems?

Comment: That sounds like what a load balancer does; react to changing backends. I haven't thought this through, and I seem to remember that the load balancing feature is still experimental in the Go libraries, but you may want to look into that.

Comment: Nope, that's not the load balancer responsibility. I could use load balancer in case of there is more than one specific plugin, for example `plugin1` has 4 instances. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Can you clarify the problem? I'm not sure I understand your concern, but from the description it seems like there shouldn't be a problem with the proposed implementation.

Comment: The problem is I should implement a client-side registry which periodically checks for the available nodes of the services and store them with labels. This is what I don't really want. I'm just thinking about a better way to implement it.